# Alamofire request completion handler crash

Tags: ios, swift, closures, alamofire, completionhandler

I am getting a crash in a release version of our app through Crashlytics, that I can not replicate on any of my devices or simulators.

My understanding from Crashlytics is that the crash is not coming from a fatal error from something in particular but from somewhere in the closure itself. It appears to be happening on line 1537 when the completion handler is called, but I can not see why. Is there a problem with my syntax from the closure, incorrect use of `@escaping`, or unwrapping of variables, or using the main thread for the completion handler (because it sit's within an Alamofire completion handler?).

The user who's getting the crash is running the same iOS as me (11) and I have logged in through her account and had no problems myself.

```
func getObjectsInBackground(completion:@escaping (_ error:AMDError?,_ objects:[Dictionary<String, Any>]?)->()){

    Alamofire.request(URL(string: urlstring)!, method: .get).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch response.result {

        case .success:


            let results = response.result.value as! NSArray

            var objects = [Dictionary<String,Any>]()

            for result in results {
                let object = result as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                objects.append(object)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {     //<<Line 1537
                completion(nil, objects )
            }


        case .failure(let error):

            let error = AMDError(code: "400", errorString: error.localizedDescription, info: nil)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(error, nil)
            }


        } 
    }
}
```

This is the info from crashlytics

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Amondo                         0x101269118 specialized MenuViewController.(loadFutureImprints() -> ()).(closure #1) (MenuViewController.swift:154)
1  Amondo                         0x101278410 partial apply for MenuViewController.(loadFutureImprints() -> ()).(closure #1) + 4311073808
2  Amondo                         0x10122a014 @callee_owned (@owned Error?, @owned [[String : Any]]?) -> ()AMDError? (AMDClasses.swift)
3  Amondo                         0x10122a128 partial apply for specialized  (AMDClasses.swift:1537)
4  Amondo                         0x101205668 thunk (AMDClasses.swift)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d45088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d45048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d51b74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016
8  CoreFoundation                 0x181367f20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181365afc __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1812862d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
11 GraphicsServices               0x183117f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
12 UIKit                          0x18a833880 UIApplicationMain + 208
13 Amondo                         0x1011fe804 main (Extensions.swift:44)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x180daa56c start + 4
```

Comment: can you also show the code for `(MenuViewController.swift:154)`

Comment: Line 154 is the line at which the class is defined -class MenuViewController:UIViewController {

Comment: are you by any chance calling `DispatchQueue.main.sync` anywhere? related to this code

Comment: No - .async yes, but .sync no

Comment: Have you figured it out?